# Persist is not working as expected on the remote session bean

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, persistence

I am having a persistence issue between 2 JEE applications communicating between 2 different Glassfish domains.

#### The basic structure

- we have two JEE applications deployed on two different domains on a Glassfish server
- Application1 is deployed on domain1 and uses the database Database1
- Application2 is deployed on domain2 and uses the database Database2
- Application1 is communicating with Application2 through a remote EJB
  session bean

#### Another view

- Glassfish 4.0

  - domain1

    - Application1 <=> Database1

      - Application1-ejb
      - Application1-war
  - domain2

    - Application2 <=> Database2

      - Application2-ejb
      - Application2-war

#### The environment

- we are using Glassfish 4.0
- we are using JDK7/JEE7 to build and deploy the applications on the
  Glassfish
- we are using EclipseLink for the persistence in the applications, I
  have enabled the eclipse logging to check the requests in the logs
- we are using MySQL for both databases
- we are using XADataSource to be able to perform requests on both
  databases in the same transaction

---

#### Test case I am using

1. A managed bean from the *Application1-war* calls local session bean from the *Application1-ejb* (when a user performs an action in the browser)
2. The local session bean from *Application1-ejb* will call the remote session bean from *Application2-ejb*
3. The remote session bean from *Application2-ejb* will persist an entity in the database *Database2*: `em.persist(entity2)`
4. The local session bean from *Application1-ejb* will persist an entity in the database *Database1*: `em.persist(entity1)`

Somehow it should be the same transaction as we are using `XADataSource`.
So if for any reason a runtime exception is occurring, the entities should not be persisted.

#### The issue

The first time the method of the *Application1-ejb* is called, it works:

- *Application2* persists the entity in the database *Database2*
- *Application1* persists the entity in the database *Database1*

The requests can be seen in the logs, and I can see the new entities in *Database1* and *Database2*.

The next times the method of the *Application1-ejb* is called, it will not work:

- *Application1* is able to call *Application2*, but even though *Application2* does call `em.persist(entity2)`, it does not persist the entity in the database *Database2*
- *Application1* persists the entity in *Database1*

The requests can be seen in the logs of the *Application1*, but no requests can be seen in the logs of the *Application2*.

The new entities can be seen in the *Database1*.
But no new entities can be seen in the *Database2*.
In the browser, it looks like the server is not giving any response to the client.

#### I have tried several things...

- Deploying the projets on a newer Glassfish (4.0 to 5.0): the problem is still occurring
- Updating MySQL's Java connector (5.1.23 to 5.1.45): the problem is still occurring
- Updating EclipseLink (2.5 to 2.5.2): the problem is still occurring

#### Hibernate

If I use Hibernate instead of EclipseLink, it will work as expected. But migrating to Hibernate is not something we can afford right now as we would have to migrate big JEE applications.

#### em.flush()

If I force the *Application2-ejb* to flush after the `em.persist(entity2)`, it will work every time, and the browser is always receiving a response from the server.

But if I flush, it means that if an exception is occurring at one point, an entity will be persisted in *Database2* (because of the flush) and no entity will be persisted in *Database1* (because of the exception), and this is not something we want too.

---

#### Some code to produce the issue

Application1/SessionBean.java

```
package application1.sessionbeans;

import application1.entities.Entity1;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import application2.sessionbeans.remote.SessionBeanRemote;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class SessionBean implements SessionBeanLocal {

    @EJB(name = "SessionBeanRemote-ejbref")
    private SessionBeanRemote sessionBeanRemote;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("SessionBean Application1");
        em.persist(new Entity1());
        sessionBeanRemote.test();
    }
}
```

Application1/glassfish-ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 EJB 3.1//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-ejb-jar_3_1-1.dtd">
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>SessionBean</ejb-name>
            <jndi-name>java:global/EnterpriseApplication1/EnterpriseApplication1-ejb/SessionBean</jndi-name>
            <ejb-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>SessionBeanRemote-ejbref</ejb-ref-name>
                <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:localhost:4537#java:global/EnterpriseApplication2/EnterpriseApplication2-ejb/SessionBean</jndi-name>
            </ejb-ref>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

Application1/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EnterpriseApplication1-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>aEnercomDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Application2/SessionBean.java

```
package application2.sessionbeans;

import application2.entities.Entity2;
import application2.sessionbeans.remote.SessionBeanRemote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class SessionBean implements SessionBeanRemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("sessionBean Application2");
        em.persist(new Entity2());
    }
}
```

Application2/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EnterpriseApplication2-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>AEnercomCollectData-DS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Application2Remote/SessionBeanRemote.java

```
package application2.sessionbeans.remote;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface SessionBeanRemote {

    public void test();

}
```

---

I tried to make the example as simple as possible.

Is there someone here who was able to persist entities without any problem between different Glassfish domains?

Is there a property we are missing in the persistence.xml to get this working?

Comment: 'But if I flush, it means that if an exception is occurring at one point, an entity will be persisted in Database2 (because of the flush) and no entity will be persisted in Database1 (because of the exception), and this is not something we want to' - why would that happen? Flushing is not the same as comitting the transaction

Comment: Yes but flushing causes the entity manager to write in the database. I can say also that when the Application1 and Application2 applications are on the same Glassfish domain, everything is working as expected.

Comment: Writing in the database is still not the same as commiting the transaction. That's the whole point of having a transaction, being able to issue multiple write statements to the db and still be able to roll them back in case anything goes wrong. In other words, if you go with the flush workaround, you should be fine

Comment: You should set a finer level of logging to maybe figure out what might be going wrong in the logs. Flush shouldn’t be required, but it is strange your method would return without throwing an error or some indication of a problem.

Comment: @crizzis I completely agree, but it seems I've found why I was not able to roll back properly after flushing. We are using MyISAM as the default storage engine for MySQL. I've just done the same test with InnoDB, and the roll back is really happenning this time if I throw an exception after the `em.flush()`

Comment: @Chris I agree, it should not be necessary to call `em.flush()` in the remote session bean. Actually, today our 2 applications are on the same Glassfish domain and the persists/updates work fine without any explicit flush

Comment: @Chris For the level of logging, I've set it to `FINEST` and no commit appears to be done if I don't flush. But if I flush I see the transaction being committed (`TX afterCompletion callback, status=COMMITTED`). So there should be a call back at one point for the remote session bean but it never happens if do not explicitely flush

Comment: @Chris At least now I understand why the server seems to wait for something. I have a weird behavior also when I stop my domains: after I try to persist to the remote session bean twice, the domains cannot be stopped, I have to kill the process manually, and in the logs of the remote session bean I can see a `java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: Précis: 00410008: Connection abort`. It seems something is never getting closed with the database